# In Linux is the kernel who handle all the TLB miss?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, virtual-memory

I'm trying to organize in my head some concepts about Linux Memory Management and have the following questions:

In Linux are the TLB misses handled by kernel code? Even the miss is a simple look up *in the page table to see whether a mapping exists (a page walk)*[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table#The_translation_process)]? I mean, are the so called *page walk* execute by kernel code?

Are the so called *page walk* (a response to some kind of TLB misses) considered soft page faults?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the processor. In the x86 architecture the TLB misses are handled by hardware, so it is transparent to the kernel. The only time kernel code deals with the TLB is when the contents of the TLB is to be discarded (a TLB flush).

A "soft page fault" usually refers to the situation when a memory page is present in RAM, but this is not known to the MMU, i.e. there is no entry for the page frame in the page tables.

Comment: " i.e. there is no entry for the page frame in the page tables" or " i.e. there is no entry for the page frame in the TLB"? I think that for a soft page fault you have to have a page in the page table, even a one with the *present bit* off.

Comment: A TLB miss does not cause a page fault on x86. On (at least some) MIPS processors a TLB miss is handled by software, but not on x86, so there is no page fault in this case, not even a "minor" or "soft" one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification Johan. Last questions, I promise ;) ... 1-) Because is hardware who handle the TLB misses in x86 architecture (I'm guessing that includes x86-64 too), the Page Table has a format independently of the OS implementation right? 2-) Is the OS who fill the page table when needed by the kernel/process? 3-) Could you put me an example of "soft page fault"? I mean, what could be the situation when "there is no entry for the page frame in the page tables" and is not segfault? page cache maybe? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, the hardware defines the page table structure, at least on x86 (including x86-64). Every process has its own page table structure starting from the Page Global Directory, which is pointed to by the CR3 register. When a context switch occurs, that is, a new process is selected for execution, a new value for the CR3 register is loaded from the new process' descriptor. In addition to the process specific user level memory mappings, all processes share a common mapping of the kernel address space. This area is accessible only when the process is in kernel mode.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on page faults mentions the case were memory is shared by different processes as an example which could lead to a soft page fault. A soft page fault is a real page fault, and result in calling a handler routine to fix the situation. The difference compared to a hard page fault is that it is easier to handle, because the data is already in RAM, and does not need to be loaded from disk. All that needs to be done is to fix the page tables of the faulting process to point to the correct page frame.